# Can't parse json data

Tags: android, json, cordova

I am making a phonegap app for android. I am receiving a json string and trying to parse it . It's a very small data. 
                  `{"result":{ "node":"32"}
                  }`

if iam using `alert(request.responseText)`
the result is displayed but if i return this request.responseText to the calling function and collect it there in a variable like `var x= somefunction(); x contains undefined.`

```
var jsonObj = sendPostRequest(url,nurl);
  console.log(jsonObj+""); // GIVES UNDEFINED HERE AT THIS LINE BUT SAME STATEMENT WORKS IN sendPostRequest()
  if(jsonObj){
    var Json = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
    console.log(json);
    document.getElementById("gnodei").innerHTML= json.result.wEventId;
  }
```

I can collect this response in a variable y inside somefunction() but on returning this data to the calling function nothing reaches there. I use the above json data x just below it but it doesn't work.

please suggest.

edit: `function sendPostRequest(url,nurl){

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0){
           console.log(request.status);
           //alert(request.responseText);
           var txt= request.responseText;
           console.log(txt);
           return txt;
          }
        }
      }

request.open("POST",url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send(nurl);
```

}`

The ajax call. Also there are multiple functions calling this ajax call after preparing their url and nurl values so i need this function as it is. I only need to know how to get back the response in my calling function.
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing your sendPostRequest is a non blocking/asynchronous call. So the value of jsonObj is not set when you try to work with it.

Comment: The suggestions from @SimonMacDonald seems to be most likely the case. Could you show us your sendPostRequest method?

Comment: @NickRoth please check the method. Hmmm, I think the lines after my call are executing immediately after my function call. If that what simon meant.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald: Thanks for your suggestion. I searched how to create blocking functions. I now send a callback function sendPostRequest(url,nurl,callBack); to my post method and this callback makes all assignments after the response is received. Thanks for pointing at the async keyword. It's working now.

Comment: Great you should answer the question yourself and make it closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:   Created a function to be passed as callback to the sendPostRequest(url,nurl) method. This callback is called only after the ajax call finishes as correct status. The callback function assigns the data that can be used thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(stringJson);
```